# How to know what parameters are available in jQuery callback functions, how to understand it and add parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently developing a map with the Openlayers 3 library and need to understand the callback functions.

I then started reading and found out I've been using callback functions with jQuery all the time.
I also read that you can use parameters that are available in these functions:

```
$('body').click(function(e){
    e.preventdefault();
)}
```

The 'e' can be used in the function.

My questions are:

1. How to know what parameters are available?
2. Can you add parameters to this function?
3. Where are these parameters defined?

I am trying to understand this because I would have to use global parameters otherwise, and using global parameters is considered 'bad practice', right?

EDIT:

So if I want to add an extra parameter to the function above, will this work:

```
document.ready(function(){
    var data = 6;
    $('body').click(function(e, data){
        e.preventdefault();
        console.log(data);
    })
 })
```

Comment: The documentation will tell you what parameters are provided to the callback.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `$.click()`? https://api.jquery.com/click/ And that's a shortcut for using `$.on()` https://api.jquery.com/on/ Specifically, see Passing Data to the Handler https://api.jquery.com/on/#passing-data

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why are you trying to add "an extra parameter" at all?

Comment: Because I don't want to set parameters globally, because it would be bad practice. Though I still need parameters inside my callback functions, I was trying to figure out another way to get the parameters available inside my callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters to the callback functions are documented in the specific API you're using.

For example, the reference for the `click`-method in jQuery can be found here: https://api.jquery.com/click/

If you want to add parameters to the function you can use variables from outside the function, they will be available inside that function:

```
document.ready(function(){
    var data = 6;
    $('body').click(function(e){ // Note: don't add 'data' in the parameter here, it will overwrite your local variable with whatever jquery passes to the function.
        e.preventdefault();
        console.log(data); // data = 6, it's available from the outer function
    })
 })
```

Since the callback will not be executed when you attach the handler (aka when you call `$("body").click()` sometimes you will need to make sure the variable that is available when executing has the same value as when the handle was attached.

Say you have the following declaration:

```
 var data = 6;
 $('body').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log(data);
 });
 data = 10;
```

In the above case, the `console.log(data)` statement will output 10. Why? Because by the time the user clicks, the last statement will already have executed and that will have modified `data` to hold the value 10.

To fix this issue, you need to capture the variable inside a closure:

```
    var data = 6;
    $('body').click((function(myVar){
        return function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(myVar);
        }
    })(data));
    data = 10;
```

Here, the value 6 will be logged to the console. Why? Instead of passing a plain function to the click-handler, you're declaring a function and immediately executing it like this:

```
(function(){
})()
```

From this IIFE(immediately invoked function expression), you return another function that will be used as the handler for the click event. The variable you pass in to the IIFE will be captured and will keep the same value as it was when you attached the click-handler

Comment: Thank you for your response. So by adding the anonymous function, you prevent losing the data, but still have to define the parameter as "global"?

Comment: No, you variable does not need to be global. It just needs to be in scope when you attach the click handler.

Comment: Awesome! I am still trying to figure out how to create scopes the right way and prevent events from reapplying, so your information helps me a lot :D